# Do the Intel X79 Chipset and 2nd Generate Core i7 Processors support VT-d?

Tags: virtualization, intel-core-i7, vt-x

**EDIT:** I have an Intel DX79TO board tested working with VT-d passthrough to VMware ESXi5. I've used multiple Core i7 38xx processors, and they have all worked so far.

I know that there were rumors [floating](http://www.bit-tech.net/news/hardware/2011/10/04/rumour-intel-discovers-sandy-bridge-e-bug/1) [around](http://www.techpowerup.com/152978/Sandy-Bridge-E-VT-d-Broken-In-C1-Stepping-Fixed-In-C2-Stepping-Shortly-After-Launch.html?cp=2) late last year that C1 stepping processors with the X79 chipset had broken support for VT-d. There are a few [specifications](http://communities.intel.com/thread/27668) available that list VT-d as being supported on this hardware, but there are also accounts that it doesn't work, and I don't want to waste a lot of money on bleeding-edge hardware that is supposed to have this feature but doesn't.

Has anyone had/does anyone have a link to someone who has had firsthand experience with VT-d working on X79/Core i7 38xx or 39xx hardware?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that most of the i7 processors have VT-d enabled on them. You can get a full list from the [Intel Ark here](http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced?VTD=true). The list will always be current as it uses a search for `VTD=true`. Just check that your motherboard has that capability. There's so many processors with it that its hard to narrow it down to "which work and which don't".

[Wikipedia does say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_2011) the following on LGA 2011 sockets:

> All models support: MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX,
>   Enhanced Intel SpeedStep Technology (EIST), Intel 64, XD bit (an NX
>   bit implementation), TXT, Intel VT-x, Intel VT-d, Turbo Boost, AES-NI,
>   Smart Cache, Hyper-threading, **except the C1 stepping models, which**
>    **lack VT-d**.

Comment: Awesome! However, it's the motherboard bit (the X79 chipset specifically) that I'm most concerned about, since there were mutterings of it not supporting VT-D. I've dug a bit, but all I've found are conflicting and less-than-authoritative statements on whether or not it works.

Comment: I can firsthand say that I've seen X79 boards with VT-d options in the BIOS.

Comment: @ZacB I added a bit that may help.

Answer (score 0):

I've verified that VT-D works (I can pass through devices to ESXi 5) on an Intel motherboard with the X79 chipset. The motherboard is a DX79TO. Might be useful for anyone else looking for definitive data on this.